# How do I check if the string "Edgar Allan Poe" contains any items of List(Of String)?

Tags: vb.net

I have a list of string:

```
Dim n As New List(Of String)
n.Add("Poe")
n.Add("Shakespeare")

Dim sAuthor As String = "Edgar Allan Poe"
```

How could I check if sAuthor contains any item of "n"?

I am missing the second argument:

```
If sAuthor.Contains(n, ...) Then
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Any method ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-6.0)):

```vb
If (n.Any(Function(item) sAuthor.Contains(item))) Then
   ' success!
End If
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/r7y5Xw

What this does is return a Boolean value based on if any item in the collection evaluates to true based on the predicate.

In this case we are saying: Is any item in my List contained in the variable?

**Update**

Since the OP indicated that the above is too difficult for them to read/debug, this is how you would do the same thing without using LINQ:

```vb
Dim anyMatch As Boolean = False
For Each item In n
    If (sAuthor.Contains(item)) Then
        anyMatch = True
        Exit For
    End If 
Next
If (anyMatch) Then
    ' success!
End If
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DPWo9m

The only (practical) difference between the two is that the above uses LINQ which provides a more concise mechanism of what is used below.

Comment: Better than mine.

Comment: Also, case-insensitive comparison example could be useful, like (.NET Framework):  `Dim b As Boolean = n.Any(Function(s) sAuthor.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)` or `.Contains(String, StringComparison)` overload on .NET Core, 6...

Comment: Thank you, but I can not use this because it's not easy to read. I find it a pain to debug something like this. It should be forbidden.

Comment: @tmighty This or loop the list to examine each item by calling `.Contains` or `.IndexOf` methods. Keep vb6 for vb6 apps and write vb.net code for vb.net apps.

Comment: @tmighty - I've updated my answer to provide a non-LINQ answer. However, I would highly encourage you to embrace LINQ. It provides a more concise way to write code and with the Visual Studio debugger, it really is not difficult to step through the code.

Comment: @tmighty you can set breakpoints in and step through inline lambda functions.  Personally, I find that the style in the original answer is more understandable as it's clearly descriptive of what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
    If (From a In n Where sAuthor.Contains(a) Select True Take 1).FirstOrDefault Then
        Stop
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have decided not to use this strange language. It looks like a quantum situation rather than real code.